# Closing pages after they have been scraped

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using this scraper http://planzero.org/blog/2013/03/07/spidering_the_web_with_casperjs
It goes to a web page, finds the links on the page, and then goes to those pages and finds the links on those pages, etc. I'm having an issue with it hogging a bunch of memory as it's running and I have a feeling it's because it's not properly closing the previous pages after it's done spidering them. I've tried adding `casper.page.close();` to various places in the app, but keep getting this error: `` Error: cannot access member `evaluate' of deleted QObject ``

Comment: If you close a page then you have to open a new one. That script uses a single page to do all of its things.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Why do you think there is such a crazy amount of memory usage, then? If it's only using one page, shouldn't it just use the amount of memory that one page would use?